# ToDo list (productivity app) with api, reminders, custom fields

Tags: api, productivity, todo

I'm looking for a cross-platform (Android and web at the very least) todo list system that has what I think would be really basic features for tech-minded people:

1. a REST-ful API (preferably with webhooks, but I suppose polling- or sync-based options might suffice)
2. Saved searches (search folders, whatever you want to call them so I can setup some AND/OR logic between my tags or custom fields)
3. Custom fields (like I get to define both the tag ("name", "key") and value)
4. Reminders (snoozable is best).
5. Free plan that has all of the above, OR a one-time purchase that isn't too expensive. But who in their right mind would pay 20 bucks a month for a todo list!

If it has more features (like file storage, email integration, etc.), that would add to the value and I might be willing to pay more, but the above are the essentials!

Answer (score 1):

It's not free but I think its worth mentioning [Todoist](https://todoist.com/).

It is BY FAR my favorite Todo app.

They have a web app, android app, iOS app, browser extensions, and webhooks (I think).

Their API is awesome I hear (haven't used it personally).

No 'custom fields' but you can add notes/comments to each todo.

A minimal feature set is available for free (useful to get a feel for it); but reminders, tags, filters, and all the other power features require a modest yearly subscription (~$30/yr).

Comment: I asked this question because I looked at Toodledo and Todoist and both require payment for reminders, but neither support custom fields. Thanks for trying, though. I'll give you some rep because you are new and will need it.

Comment: my main problem with Todoist is that it allows you to snooze Due Dates, not reminders.  Very backward! When IRL do you snooze a due date? Very rarely, unless you are using the due date for the wrong purpose!